Error in discrete FFT
I am interested in taking an FFT of an image which is periodic in space (does not decay) across a finite window of size $L\times L$. The image has triangular symmetry; for simplicity one could imagine the function to be something akin to
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m} W(|n\mathbf{Q}_1+m\mathbf{Q}_2|) \,\cos((n\mathbf{Q}_1+m\mathbf{Q}_2)\cdot\mathbf{r}) 
$$
where $\mathbf{r} = (x,y)$, $\mathbf{Q}_1=(1,0)$ and $\mathbf{Q}_1=(-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)$, i.e. a sum of harmonics of an underlying triangular lattice. It is also the case that $W(|\mathbf{q}|)\rightarrow 0$ as $|\mathbf{q}|\rightarrow \infty$, perhaps exponetially quickly.
The Fourier transform has equal weight at the two frequencies related by $2\pi/3$ rotation, $\tilde{f}_{\mathbf{Q}_1} = \tilde{f}_{\mathbf{Q}_2} = W$. But if I perform the FFT on a square grid, there will be spurious rotational symmetry breaking in my estimates of these two Fourier components, due to the fact my grid does not have threefold rotational symmetry.
I would like to know how to bound the error introduced by the square grid. For instance, if I wish $|\tilde{f}_{\mathbf{Q}_1} - \tilde{f}_{\mathbf{Q}_2}| < \varepsilon$, what grid spacing $L/N$ is necessary?
Given the practical importance and simplicity of this question, I am certain this question is bread and butter to people in for e.g. signal processing; apologies if this question is a duplicate or has an obvious answer.

I suspect I may be misunderstanding the problem, but it seems that if $f(x,y)$ is appropriately bandlimited, then you will have zero reconstruction error. OTOH, if $f(x,y)$ is not bandlimited, then you will have reconstruction error. I guess I'm suggesting that the symmetries may be a red herring in understanding the error term-- they don't have to align with any symmetries in your data.

@BillBradley Hi Bill, perhaps I chose a poor example since there are only two frequencies in my function. I have adjusted the question to be more realistic -- my function contains all harmonics of $\mathbf{Q}_1$ and $\mathbf{Q}_2$, but their coefficients decay very rapidly (perhaps exponentially). I am unsure if this changes things significantly, would be interested to hear your thoughts.
